# what will be the output of the java script code?

Tags: javascript

```
 var a = {};
 b = {x:4};
 c = {y: 2};
a[b] = 123; 
a[c] = 456;

console.log(a[b]);
```

I was thinking, output should be 123 but not, I do not know..

> what will be the output and explain with reason

Comment: What was the result when you ran it?

Comment: Both `b` and `c` translate to `[object Object]` so they both occupy the same key in `a`

Comment: When using bracket notation `a[b]`, `b` needs to be a string, not an object.

Comment: The time you wasted posting this question on stack overflow is greater than the time you should have tried running it on jsfiddle/hackerrank or any online code editor.

Comment: It returns 456 but I don't know how it comes.

Answer (score 1):

```
The output will be 456
// It creates an empty object
var a = {};
b = {
  x: 4
}; // b become a new object
c = {
  y: 2
}; // c become a new object
/**Next line trying to create a key in object a which will look like {x:4}
which is invalid so it will look like {[object Object]} and its value will be 123**/
a[b] = 123;
/**Same operation with following line and its value will be 456.
In this case the previous[object Object] will be over written by
new one so both occupy the same key and hence 123 is overwritten 456**/
a[c] = 456;
```